# copy data from datatable to dataset.datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to copy data from datatable to table in dataset i ry this but its readonly property

```
ds.datatable1=newdt.copy
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what you are trying to do here? BTW, copy is a method so it should be `newdt.Copy()`; note the brackets at the end. Also what kind of dataset is `ds`? I am pretty sure the standard Dataset class has no property called `datatable1`

Comment: ds is variable name for my dataset and datatable1 is table alrady created by my in designer and i want to fill it from another datatable , the brackets does not matter cause i am using vb.net ,the problem i cant use dataset.innertable=datatable.copy

Comment: Just a possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897080/...][1]

Answer (score 0):

if `datatable1` is a pre-existing datatable in your code and you want to fill it from another datatable `newdt`, then just doing `datatable1 = newdt.copy` should suffice.

Remove the `ds.`from your code. If you already have a reference to the datatable in your dataset i.e. dataTable1, then you can just copy into it directly as above

Answer (score -1):

```
DataTable newdt = ds.datatable1;

newdt = Fill Datatable form DB;

ds.datatable1.TableName = "datatable1";
```