# Copy DataTable from one DataSet to another

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I'm trying to add to a new DataSet X a DataTable that is inside of a different DataSet Y.
If I add it directly, I get the following error:

> *DataTable already belongs to another DataSet.*

Do I have to clone the DataTable and import all the rows to it and then add the new DataTable to the new DataSet? Is there a better/easy way to do it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do this:

### `DataTable.Copy`

Instead of [`DataTable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx), use [**`DataTable.Copy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) to create a copy of your data table; then insert the copy into the target `DataSet`:

```
dataSetX.Tables.Add( dataTableFromDataSetY.Copy() );
```

### `DataSet.Merge`

You could also use [**`DataSet.Merge`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx) for this:

```
dataSetX.Merge(dataTableFromDataSetY);
```

Note, however, that if you are going to use this method, you might want to make sure that your target `DataSet` doesn't already contain a table with the same name:

- If the target DataSet doesn't contain a table by the same name, a fresh copy of the table is created inside the data set;
- If a table by the same name is already in the target data set, then it will get merged with the one passed to `Merge`, and you end up with a mix of the two.

Answer (score 4):

Use this generic function

```
public DataTable CopyDataTable(DataTable dtSource, int iRowsNeeded)
{

    if (dtSource.Rows.Count > iRowsNeeded)
    {
        // cloned to get the structure of source
        DataTable dtDestination = dtSource.Clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < iRowsNeeded; i++)
        {
            dtDestination.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows[i]);
        }
        return dtDestination;
    }
    else
        return dtSource;
}
```

Suppose you want to copy first table of sourceSet to destinationSet.
Call it like

```
DataTable destinationTable = CopyDataTable(sourceSet.Tables[0], sourceSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
DataSet destinationSet = new DataSet();
destinationSet.Tables.Add(destinationTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
X.Tables.Add(Y.Tables[<tablename|index>].Copy());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =  from sourceTbl in sourceTbl.AsEnumerable()
where [any condition you want]
select order;
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

I am not sure If i understood your question properly.Hope this code helps